# why is my paypal button not clicable

Tags: css, paypal

i'm getting crazy with a problem that is probably a stupid thing.

Yesterday, i make some little design change on a site, to get the paypal button displayed on a second column of an area.

But since it is displayed this way, when i click on "acheter" ( buy now ) nothings happen.

I have tryied to generate a brand new button thru paypal, thinking i have probably deleted essential element, but same problem.

Button can be seen here : (bottom of the page)

https://www.soutien-psy-en-ligne.fr/consultation-en-ligne/honoraires/

if i take of all my html custom and leave just the paypal form, it works well again :o

Here is a capture of the form to help you identify it on the website
[image: capture]

Comment: Flagged as this isn't WordPress related. Suggested it's moved to StackOverflow.

Comment: ok, but this is on a wordpress based website. So i dont know if it can has incidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is broken. Check your quotes at

```
<div class="paiement-honoraires-right>
```

Comment: yes, just find the issue, was coming to add answear ! Thanks for your help. That was it !